# Can I pipe stderr to `foo`'s stdin and stdout to `bar`'stdin?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have two Python files, `data-writer.py` and `logs-writer.py`. The former writes stdin to `foo.data`; the latter writes stdin to `foo.log`.

Given a process `p`, how do I pipe its stdout to `data-writer.py`'s stdin, and stderr to `logs-writer.py`'s stdin?

Answer (score 2):

Using process substitutions

```
p > >(data-writer.py) 2> >(logs-writer.py)
```